# jQuery UI - Convert jQuery UI Datepicker to UNIX time

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, datepicker, datetimepicker, unix-timestamp

I'm using jQuery UI datepicker with time plugin. This is how I display time on the page in datepicker itself:

```
21.06.2012 08:00
```

I'd like to convert this time to UNIX timestamp before sending to backend. How can I do this?
I don't need to dispay UNIX time on the page, I only need to convert before posting. I've tried:

```
var d = Date.parse(value_of_datepicker);
```

but had no luck. It seems date should be formated in another way. Also I've tried several build-in datepicker functions, but all of them set date display view. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use jQuery timepicker by Trent Richardson, you can do this: `$("#your_datepicker").datetimepicker("getDate").getTime() / 1000`

http://jsfiddle.net/d6Tky/

Remember that this function may return null if no date has been selected.

Comment: I'm running this, but it seems to be off by one hour early. Any updates on why this could be happening?

Comment: Problem seems to be linked with wrong time zone or daylight saving. Probably, you should check this article of Trent Richardson: http://trentrichardson.com/2011/03/04/timepicker-gets-time-zone/